# Получить текст кнопки GUI Unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, gui

В Unity создал GUI элемент `Button`, через визуальный редактор присвоил ему текст `"Hello"`. Собственно вопрос: Как в коде добраться до элемента кнопки и получить его значения `Text` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод для получения объекта кнопки

```
public Button GetButton(string caption)
{
    var go = GameObject.Find(caption);
    var button = go.GetComponent<Button>();
    return button;
}
```

Текст кнопки находится в свойстве `text`.